# How to prevent files from being checked out to the default changelist in perforce?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to revert the setting in Perforce Visual Client (Mac OSX 10.6.8) so that the checked out files are not by default checked out in the 'default' changelist ? I am failing to find any option in the preferences pane.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in Preferences -> Behavior, "Prompt for changelist when checking out, adding, or deleting files"

[image]

Comment: Gosh ! That really saved my day :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion that `Mike O'Connor` gave me was great, but it didn't work for me.

I solved the problem in this way. I hope it helps.

In the Visual Studio menu bar, right-click and open the context menu. Then, check the `Helix Connection` option. You should see something like this.

[image: 1]

and just change changelist `Default` to `<Prompt for changelist>`

[image]